# Generating java code from wsdl using cxf gives code too large error

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, code-generation, cxf

I have generated the code form wsdl to java using cxf 2.7.3 but when building the assembly I get "code too large" error. Indicating that one of the methods have exceeded java 64kb limit. I know exactly which class and to me this seems like bug in cxf. Actully Axis2 does the same so I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this.

The code I'm playing around with is provided [here](https://github.com/e-conomic/eco-api-ex.git) in path eco-api-ex / examples / java /

How can I force the code generation to split up large generated method? or should I use some external tool for this?

```
[ERROR] \workspace\e-conomics\target\generated\src\main\java\com\e_conomic\Econo
micWebServiceSoap_EconomicWebServiceSoap12_Client.java:[34,23] error: code too l
arge
```

Comment: Just how large _is_ that WSDL document?

Comment: See for your self.. its long https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?wsdl i'm trying to integrate to this service..  my second idea is to download and take away what I dont need..

Comment: That's the sort of document whose download ought to be accompanied by the classic Worms sound effect: “Incoming!”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't run wsdl2java with the -client flag.  The _Client.java class is just a sample class to show how to use the generated service class and proxies and such.  It's not normally needed for anything.  That SHOULD be the only class generated with a large method like that.

Comment: I should have said that I have removed that and I'm running the latest cxf and I also tried Axis2. Axis comes further but blows up at line 68608 :), saying "code too large". It is not my wsdl or service I'm just trying to integrate.

Comment: If you removed that, then you should have a new error or classname.  The error would no longer be in Econo
micWebServiceSoap_EconomicWebServiceSoap12_Client.java as that wouldn't be generated.  Can you update with the new location?

Comment: Actually I removed what I didn't need from the wsdl (3mb->2.4mb) to get it compile and it all worked great. I came around to post the second error for your request but this time around it just worked with the entire 3mb wsdl. What I did differently is having the WSDL locally. Any how the -client flag as you mentioned and as I tried before was causing the problem combined with not having it locally, good for someone with similar problems to know.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a 3MB WSDL document there. (No wonder my browser was a bit unhappy when I tried to view a general XML document of that size.) It's got around 3000 elements defined in it; also 3k messages and 4.5k operations. I don't know exactly what you're hitting the limit in (there's a few places where registries of all entities of a particular type are constructed) but it doesn't matter too much. It's just far too large for most code to normally handle. (The limit you're hitting appears to be the one on the total size of bytecode for a method; hitting that is usually an indication of something somewhere else going badly awry: in this case, it's the bunker-busting WSDL document.)

Constructing a cut-down version that has a much smaller set of elements, messages and operations would be an excellent idea. Putting that cut-down version in your repository where Maven can find it (e.g., in `src/main/wsdl`) would also make a lot of sense, as it would stop you from downloading that 3MB document again each time you build.

Comment: I know, was hoping for a silver bullet here, how fun can it be to edit a 3000 element wsdl? Tomorrow they edit their api and suddenly nothing works again.. was hoping not go the manual brute force road..